# RavenDB Error: I can't access var store from a different class. Any Suggestions

Tags: c#, database, error-handling, ravendb, non-relational-database

RavenDB Error: var store isn't a global variable. How do I create a class that can use access documentstore? Any comments on why this code refuses to run is greatly appreciated

```
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var store = new DocumentStore
            {
                Urls = new[] { "http://localhost:8080" },
                Database = "Tasks"
            };

            store.Initialize();

        }
     class OtherProgram

        using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
                    {
                        var task = session.Load<Entity>(combinedInitial + email)
//More code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you would use a single document-store instance per application (**singleton**).

**See the common pattern for initializing the DocumetnStore here**:
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#the-document-store

See walkthrough and explanations in this **demo**:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/basics/the-document-store

Can also follow the example in the **Bootcamp repository**
https://github.com/ravendb/bootcamp/tree/v5.x/src/unit1/lesson4#exercise-moving-the-documentstore-instance-to-a-singleton-class